# Regex matching specific url

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to test if a url with a wildcard at the end matches with another one.

```
^http?://(?:www\\.)?lichess\\.org/?.*
```

is my regex, I want it to match with http://en.lichess.org/e2KWZt0Y, everything after .org/ should be random.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Firstly, in most languages regexps need to be between // , secondly what output are you getting currently ?

Comment: to match // after http: use \/\/ it is often useful to start very small, and build up slowly.

Comment: Could you `split` it out instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
/(http:\/\/en\.lichess\.org\/)((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))/i
```

Like This:

```
var string = 'http://en.lichess.org/e2KWZt0Y';
var match = string.match(/(http:\/\/en\.lichess\.org\/)((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))/i);
if(match && match.length){
    console.log('Match Found');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

based on what you have said and the regex you showed, i would try the following

```
/(^http?:\/\/en.lichess.org\/?.*)/i
```

As a tip i recommend using [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to test your regex

Answer (score 0):

The `http?` expression has two possible values:

- http
- htt

As I see it, you wanted to handle HTTP and HTTPS protocols, so the correct whole expression is:

```
/(^https?:\/\/en.lichess.org\/?.*)/i
```